# Unknown character in JavaScript string in Chrome Devtools

Tags: javascript, html, string, google-chrome, ecmascript-6

I am trying to search the presence of a substring in another string in ES6, which fails even though the target string contains the search text.

After inspecting the string in devtools, I found a small new-line like character in the string which was breaking my search. You can see it in the screenshot before the word `today`. However, it doesn't show up in the browser (the image just above the devtools), I am not sure where it's coming from.

What is this character, and how do I strip it out from my string?

(I am sure this is a duplicate question, but I just don't know what to search for, so if anyone can point out to the duplicate question, I'd be more than happy to close this one.)

[image]

Comment: Unless the element is `<pre>` or has `style="white-space: pre"`, the browser wraps lines when it renders text, so you can't see where the newlines were in the original text.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I wrapped my text in `<pre>` tag and that shows there was a linebreak in the original string. What is that character called, and how do I get rid of  it so my search can work?

Answer (score 1):

This is how Google Chrome displays an otherwise non-printable sequence of characters in the developer console. In this case, the sequence of characters is a Carriage Return (CR) + Line Feed (LF). The CR moves the cursor to the beginning of the line and the LF moves the cursor one line forward. This simply signifies a string that contains a newline.

Comment: Thanks, I replaced all the newline characters from the string using the expression  `s.replace(/[\n\r]/g, '')` and it got my search working.